# If I use a while loop in a for loop, shouldn't the while loop repeat according to the range of the for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

It's like if I use for loop with range x, in another for loop with range y; then the inner for loop runs y*x times.

Example:

```
    for i in range(6): 
        for j in range(20):
            print('*',end=' ')
        print( )
```

Output:

```
********************
********************
********************
********************
********************
********************
```

```
    j=1
    for i in range(6): 
       while j<21:
            print('*',end=' ')
            j+=1
       print( )
```

Expected:

```
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
```

Result:

```
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
```

Comment: Idk why won't the stars show up here and only empty lines are visible in place of the output.

Comment: Because `**` is markdown to make text *italic*

Comment: Whatever, my only doubt is that why the output with the while loop inside the for loop only has one row of stars instead of 6 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of the `j` variable is not reset as it is declared outside the loop.
You have to reset the variable every time you leave the `while` loop, or just declare it inside the loop as the following : 
**First possibility :**

```
j = 1
for i in range(6): 
   while j<21:
        print('*',end=' ')
        j+=1
   j = 1
   print( )
```

**Second possibility (Best one):**

```
for i in range(6): 
   j = 1
   while j<21:
        print('*',end=' ')
        j+=1
   print( )
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a mistake in the second statement... You should reset the `j` variable inside the for loop:

```
for i in range(6): 
   j=1
   while j<21:
        print('*',end=' ')
        j+=1
   print( )
```

Answer (score 0):

You never reset j for the next iteration

so the next iteration of the outer for loop, j starts on 21

```
for i in range(6):
   j = 1
   while j<21:
```

Answer (score 0):

Reset your J variable in every for cycle

```
for i in range(6): 
   j=1
   while j<21:
        print('*',end=' ')
        j+=1
   print( )
```